# return method reference of object that created inside the method

Tags: java, method-reference

i'm trying to understand some scenario i ran into related to method-reference. i have a method that create an object and then return a method reference based on that object. when the function ends, and i'm using this method reference outside , the response corresponds to the object that was created inside the method. wasn't it was supposed to be deleted by the garbage collector? how come i can still see it after the method ends?

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class A {
    public String str;
    public A(){}
    public A(String str){
        this.str = str;
    }

    public String print(String msg) {
        return msg + " " + this.str;
    }
    public Function<String, String> func(){
        A a = new A("cat");
        return a::print;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a1 = new A();
        Function<String, String> foo = a1.func();
        System.out.println(foo.apply("animals: "));
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
animals:  cat
```

i expected some error, not "cat".

Comment: GC won't remove data that is accessible. There's no way that you would ever find a variable empty because the GC removed it, unless you use weak references.

Comment: "wasn't it was supposed to be deleted by the garbage collector?" No.

Comment: @Kayaman i guess i don't understand why it is accessible. or what really returned from func, if i was returning a - i see why it's accessible. but method-reference isn't an object, so i'm a little confused

Comment: Method reference, referencing `a`. You're overthinking things, the GC removes _garbage_. It doesn't affect functioning code that depends on things. If you want to see the GC remove a reference, use `WeakReference`.

Comment: A method reference in Java isn't really a method reference, just a special lambda syntax. The lambda has a reference to the `A` created in `func` and calls `print` on it when invoked.

Comment: As @Kayaman said, you are overthinking it. Since you are accessing it, it is obviously accessible. That’s the end of the story. Garbage collectors have been invented to prevent programs from breaking, not to break them.